# Question about finite preimeter in $\operatorname{BV}$ space

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

Given $\Omega\subset \Bbb R^N$ is open bounded, we say $E\subset \Omega$ has finite perimeter in $\Omega$ if $\chi_E\in \operatorname{BV}(\Omega)$.

Follows from Evans & Gariepy's book, we write for any $\varphi\in C_c^1(\Omega,R^N)$, if $E$ has finite perimeter then we have
$$\int_E \text{div }\varphi dx =\int_\Omega \varphi\cdot \gamma\,\, d\|\partial E\|$$
where $\|\partial E\|$ denote the Radon measure which is the distribution derivative of $\chi_E$.

Question:

> Prove that the measure $\|\partial E\|$ is supported inside $\partial E$.

(This comes from Evans & Gariepy, and actually, from Ambrosio, Fusco, Pallara as well.)

My effort:

Pick up any ball $B$ such that $B\cap \partial E=\varnothing$ and try to show that $\|\partial E\|(B)=0$. But it does not really work if I only know the definition I wrote above...

Any help would be really appreciate!!

Comment: How do we define $\partial E$ in a meaningful way?

Comment: Hmm, I think $\partial E$ is just the topological boundary of $E$, i.e. $\partial E=\bar{E}\setminus E$. This is well-defined for any open set...

Comment: Yew, but now everything is defined up to a set of measure zero. So if we take away a countable dense subset from $E$, $\partial E$ would be the whole $\overline E$.

Comment: I think only the function $u$ is defined up to a set of measure zero but the set $E$ is defined, as it is in topological sense... Certainly if we take $E$ has smooth boundary then $\|\partial E\|(\Omega)=\mathcal{H}^{N-1}(\partial E\cap \Omega)$ which indeed makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here I discovered my answer... it is simple... really...

The key idea is what do we mean by $\|\partial E\|$ is supported inside $\partial E$. We need to show that for any open side $E$ such that $E\cap\partial E = \varnothing$ then we have $\|\partial E\|(B)=0$.

Next, what is $\|\partial E\|(B)$? It is 
$$\sup\left\{\int_E \text{div} \varphi\,dx,\,\,\varphi\in C_c^1(B),\,\,\|\varphi\|_{L^\infty}\leq 1 \right\} $$

Therefore, if $B$ is outside $E$, we done; if it is inside $E$, by Green theorem, we done too...